# How do I create a column which takes a date from another column in R?

Tags: r, regex, date, dplyr

I have a data frame of a few columns, the last one is called a `Filename`. This is how it looks like.

```
    Product Company Filename
       …        …       mg-tvd_bmmh_20170930.csv
       …        …       mg-tvd_bmmh_2016_06_13.csv
       …        …       …
```

I am trying to write a short script in R which takes dates from a filename and transforms it into a new column which I call a `Date`. So a new data frame would look like this:

```
     Product    Company   Date          Filename
       …          …       09/30/2017    mg-tvd_bmmh_20170930.csv
       …          …       16/13/2017    mg-tvd_bmmh_2016_06_13.csv
       …          …        …                …
```

This is a relevant piece of my script.

```
   df <- mutate(df, Date <- grep(pattern = "(\d{4})_?(\d{2})_?
   (\d{1,2})", df$Filename, value = TRUE))
   ddf$Date <- as.Date(Date,format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

Any advice why I can't get it working?

I am getting these errors:

> ```
>  Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(\d"
>  Error in as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%y") :
>    object 'Date' not found
> ```

Comment: where is it erroring?  it looks like your date format line should be  ddf$Date <- as.Date(Date,format = "%Y%m%d")

Comment: >      Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(\d"
>      Error in as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%y") :
       object 'Date' not found

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command:

```
transform(df, Date = as.Date(sub(".*\\D(\\d{4})_?(\\d{2})_?(\\d{1,2}).*",
                                 "\\1\\2\\3", Filename), "%Y%m%d"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because instead of:

```
ddf$Date <- as.Date(Date,format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

you should have:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

or:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(df$Date,format = "%Y/%m/%d"))
```

The incorrect specification of `format = "%m/%d/%y"` would give you NA values in `Date` while the incorrect reference of `as.Date(Date, ...` would throw you the error.

You can also use `str_extract` from `stringr` to extract the dates and `ymd` from `lubridate` to parse it to Date object:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(str_extract(Filename, "\\d{4}_?\\d{2}_?\\d{2}(?=\\.csv)")))
```

**Data:**

```
  Product Company                   Filename       Date
1       1       3   mg-tvd_bmmh_20170930.csv 2017-09-30
2       2       4 mg-tvd_bmmh_2016_06_13.csv 2016-06-13
```

The advantage with `ymd` is that it *"...recognize arbitrary non-digit separators as well as no separator..."* So there is no need to standardize the `Date` character vector before parsing. For instance,

```
> df$Filename %>% str_extract("\\d{4}_?\\d{2}_?\\d{2}(?=\\.csv)")
[1] "20170930"   "2016_06_13"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you show is originating because special characters in regex need to be double escaped in R (e.g. `\d` should be `\\d`). I would suggest using `sub` for the regex portion so you can control the output, and adding wildcards (`*`) after the underscores to get matches if there is or is not an underscore (like your example shows).

Formatting in `as.Date` wants a capital Y (`%Y`) for year.

The updated code would be:

```
df <- mutate(df, Date = sub(pattern = ".*_(\\d{4})_*(\\d{2})_*(\\d{1,2}).*", "\\2/\\3/\\1", df$Filename))  
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```